# Why do mac and synology report different file sizes?

Tags: filesystems, macbook, finder, synology-diskstation

I have files on my MacBookPro that I copy into Synology.
I have noticed that Finder and FileStation show different file size.

I have attached a screenshot for both these.
Finder on MacBookPro.
[image]

And on FileStation on Synology.
[image]

Why is this happening?
Is there some config setting that I can change on either of the systems that will show the same size on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS is using 10-based (decimal) prefixes, while Synology is using 2-based (binary) prefixes.

In 10-based units, 1 GB (gigabyte) = 1000×1000×1000 B.

In 2-based units, 1 GB ([gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)) = 1024×1024×1024 B (1024 = 2<sup>10</sup>).

2.69 GB ≈ 2.51 GiB: [click](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.69+GB+to+GiB).

File sizes are usually expressed in binary units. Decimal units are only used by storage manufacturers, because 8 GB HDD is more impressive than 7.45 GiB.

Synology's fault is that they're not indicating units correctly (GiB is the correct unit for binary prefixes). Apple's fault is that they're not using conventional binary units for file sizes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You're right, I've fixed it. Thanks!